# Из Array в псевдомассив

Tags: javascript, массивы

Многие спрашивают, как NodeList, HTMLColletion и другой псевдомассив превратить в Array. Так мне нужно наоборот. То есть мне нужно превратить Array, к примеру, в NodeList.

Как это сделать?

Есть два "но":

1. Я не знаю что у меня именно: NodeList, HTMLColletion или какой-то другой псевдомассив; но у меня есть псевдомассив с тем прото, в который нужно превратить массив.
2. Варианты с изменением через параметр `__proto__` не предлагать, так как мне нужен вариант, который сработает, как минимум, в IE10

Comment: Как минимум могу подсказать функцию по проверке на псевдомассив. [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048547/checking-if-an-object-is-array-like), возможно пригодится. Функция `canAccessAsArray`

Comment: В общем случае это невозможно, потому что native object не может быть создав в обход api.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, суть в том, что мне нужно, чтобы только функционал из этого прото работал на данном массиве

Comment: @Yuri это тоже в общем случае невозможно - методы не обязаны работать с "неродными" объектами. Но можете попытаться что-нибудь сделать через [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) (IE9+)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, или же все псевдомассивы преобразовывать в массивы и там уже колдовать над свойствами... или над чем там колдовать можно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению, искусственно создать псевдомассив (массивоподобный объект), вроде NodeList и HTMLCollection, никак нельзя, даже с помощью свойства `__proto__`.

Когда вы измените `__proto__` массива, то он просто изменит "родителя" с `Array` на другой, который вы укажите при смене. Тем самым изменить стандартные свойства с `Array.prototype` на `[{Object}].prototype`.

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('div');
var array = [document.querySelector('div')];

// Изменяем прото массива
array.__proto__ = NodeList.prototype;

// Проверяем содержимое обоих элементов
console.log(elements); // [<div></div>, item, entries, forEach, keys, values]
console.log(array); // [<div></div>, item, entries, forEach, keys, values]

// Провряем тип элементов
console.log({}.toString.call(elements)); // [object NodeList]
console.log({}.toString.call(array)); // [object NodeList]

// Но тут сюрприз
console.log(Array.isArray(elements)); // false
console.log(Array.isArray(array)); // true
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Как видно из примера, массив не перестал быть массивом, но чисто визуально и по типу объекта он выглядит, как NodeList.

Технически, псевдомассивом может быть любой объект, у которого внутри есть свойство length, которое должно быть целым положительным числом. По крайней мере, `Array.from()` обращает внимание в основном на это свойство.

```js
Object.canAccessAsArray = function(object) {
  return Number.isInteger(Number(object.length)) && Number(object.length) >= 0;
};

// Тут выдаст массив с тремя пустыми значениями
console.log( Object.canAccessAsArray({length: 3}) + ' => ' + Array.from({length: 3}) );
// А тут есть значения
console.log( Object.canAccessAsArray({'0': 'a', '1': 'b', '2': 'c', length: 3}) + ' => ' + Array.from({'0': 'a', '1': 'b', '2': 'c', length: 3}) );
// А тут будет пустой массив, из за отсутствия length
console.log( Object.canAccessAsArray({'0': 'a', '1': 'b', '2': 'c'}) + ' => ' + Array.from({'0': 'a', '1': 'b', '2': 'c'}) );
```